# Spring data jpa like query compatible with Oracle and Postgres

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring data repository with the following method.

```
Page<FooEntity> findAllByTenantNameAndEventTypeContainingIgnoreCaseAndReferenceContainingIgnoreCaseAndSourceServiceInIgnoreCase( //NOSONAR
        String tenantName,
        String eventType,
        String reference,
        List<String> services,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Whenever the values for fields: **tenantName**, **eventType**, **reference** are empty, in Postgres it returns the expected list.

But for the Oracle database, it doesn't return the data.

I know this is because **Oracle** internally translates empty string to null. I am getting no data because of it.

How can I make this query method compatible with both **Postgres** and **Oracle**?

Comment: The weight you seem to give to meaningful method naming is commendable... `findAllByTenantNameAndEventTypeContainingIgnoreCaseAndReferenceContainingIgnoreCaseAndSourceServiceInIgnoreCase`

Comment: Are you being sarcastic? :D

Comment: Nope. This is uncommon and I had to learn it the hard way in a place I worked before (even if I don't exactly do it like that, I still think there's value in taking it seriously)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no fix for this on database level - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF51081 where even Oracle acknowledges the fact that this is not optimal:

> Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings the same as nulls.

So as for your problem, I guess you need to find a way to solve this on application level.